# How does face snapping work?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode, snapping

I am new to blender and I was following this tutorial to make a donut.
But when it comes to the cream on top I cant deform the mesh on top to make it creamy so I end up with two ugly meshes.  I did like in the tutorial and enabled snap face, is there somthing am missing?

[image: as u can see the top mesh is in the donuts]

Comment: try select just the outer loop of vertexes and hide inside vertexes , when you do what you doing it tries snaping All of them to donat base mesh so it mess things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to have more faces on the donut than on your icing.
You can do this by adding a subdivision subsurface, you don't have to apply it.

If this doesn't work as well, you can use the shrinkwrap modifier. Make sure this is below the subdivision subsurface modifier.
Go to the modifier tab and add a shrinkwrap modifier. You will also need more verts on the donut than on the icing while doing this.

Good luck with your donut!
Emiel